# How to change the background color in listview

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm using the below code to display userResults list using listview widget. I want the background color of the individual rows to be light gray. but its using my theme primary color. could you please provide suggestions?

```
return Container(
          color: Colors.grey[50],
          child: ListView(children: userResults),
        );
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvSXL.png)

Comment: I guess we need more context or a short UI detail of your userResults

Comment: Thanks. I was able to resolve the problem. The container color scheme was overwritten by another color scheme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code should work however if any of the children of that `Container` have a color property it will over ride the grey color you have assigned. As for the `PrimaryColor` property that should not be coming into play here have you assigned any other `ThemeData` besides `PrimaryColor`

Comment: i only have one children in that container. Regarding Themedata, I assigned primarySwatch and accentcolor.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to resolve the problem. The container color scheme was overwritten by another color scheme.